# Create files based on user input (bash)

Tags: bash, macos

The assignment I am currently doing is asking me to create a script that asks users to enter the number of files they want to create. I am new to bash and am having a hard time figuring out how to create a file that will also execute the name file_timestamp. My code is down below.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the amount of files you want to create: "
read $REPLY
for i in $(eval echo "{1..100}")
do
         touch file_timestamp.txt
         
done
```

Comment: I suggest you paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net for some automated analysis.

Comment: You don't really want the hardcoded "100" in the loop. What variable holds the upper limit?

Comment: @glennjackman in the hint given it demonstrates START=1 and END=<you will receive the number of files you want to create>.  then.   (eval echo {$START..$END}

Comment: "you will receive the number" is different from "asks users to enter the number". What is the "user interface" of this program supposed to be?

Comment: @glennjackman its command line interface. and no, it says that in the hint but the instructions say "Prompt user to enter the number of files he/she wants to create". I am using bash on mac

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you asking how to execute a literal name? Because that can be done with ./ as in ./file_timestamp.txt . But the code shown makes no sense. Why are you 'eval'ing echo, and why are you echoing a parameter expansion, and why are you executing the output of that eval, and then using that as a range, and why are you trying to touch the same file file_timestamp.txt 100 times? And why bother asking the user for a number if you never use what they gave you?

Comment: `eval` is only one character away from `evil` and it should never be used where there is a standard way to accomplish what you are attempting to do. Bash provides both C-style `for` loops (e.g. `for ((i = 0; i < $end; i++)); do ... done` as well as a simple `while` loop with a counter, e.g. `n=0; while [ "$n" -lt "$end" ]; do ... n=$((n+1)); done`. (**note:** the `$` on `$end` is options when used within `(( ... ))`, so for the `for` loop, `for ((i = 0; i < end; i++)); do .. done` is also correct)

Comment: Hint, `date` allows you to create a timestamp with nanosecond precision with `date '+%s.%N'`. `touch` creates an empty file with the name given, so using `touch` with `date` in a command substitution can create the filestamped files, e.g. `touch $(date '+%s.%N')` which you could put where I have `...` in the loops above. ( you can also use `:` as a no-op and redirection to create the files as a shortcut, e.g. `:> $(date '+%s.%N')` ) up to you. Either way you create files with names of `seconds-since-epoch.nanoseconds`, e.g. `1658008489.420120547`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I never used eval until it showed it in the hint. And if I do use ((i = 0; i < $end; i++)) what would be the logic then? If I want to create a file depending on the number of files the user put. I am sorry, I am new and taking intro to scripting class.

Comment: Hah -- read both comments together -- that should get you going. If not, drop another comment. Also -- Don't use `UPPERCASE` variable names. Those are traditionally reserved for bash internal variables and environment variables. Also, you can create the timestamp in whatever format you like by using the correct conversion specifiers in the `date` format string, e.g. `'+format'`. See [man 1 date](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin how do you connect touch $(date +'%s.%N') with the file name you want to put it as?

Comment: `touch` creates the file. So whatever you put after it will be the file name. Like `touch "my-dog-has-fleas-$(date '+%s.%N')"` will create the filename like `"my-dog-has-fleas-1658008489.420120547"`. You can put whatever fixed or variable text you like along with the date command substitution enclosed in double-quotes. (your using Unix/Linux now so avoid putting spaces in filenames -- that just makes life tougher on you...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank u thank u! but how do I incorporate "enter the amount of files you want to create" with the touch logic so that lets say if I put 5. Then 5 files would be created.

Comment: Note: you should always double-quote your filename, so `touch "$(date '+%s.%N')"` would be correct. I was lazy because I knew the  `'+%s.%N'` format did not contain whitespace, but I shouldn't have been. Double quote all variables.

Comment: That comes before you enter the loop. That's how you get your `end` variable to use with the loop. So just `read -r -p "enter the amount of files you want to create: " end` to read `end`, then you should check that it is an valid integer value, e.g. `[ "$end" -eq "$end" 2>/dev/null ] || { echo "error: invalid integer"; exit 1; }` -- which just uses `[ .. ]` to check if `end` is equal to itself numerically. You can also use `[[ $end =~ [0-9]+ ]]` which uses the extended REGEX to ensure all character are digits in `end` -- up to you. Another proper test is `[[ $end =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]]`

Comment: So your script should start with `#!/bin/bash` and then you should prompt the user and read the value into `end`. You should check that `end` is a valid integer (and you may want to check it is less than 1000 or whatever max number of files you want to create). Then just loop using the `for` or `while` loops and in your loop create a new file with the timestamp each iteration. Take it step by step. Don't forget to `# comment your script` explaining what each step does so when you look at it again 6-months from now, it's easy to understand.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you very much for the help, when validating the integer do you just enter [[ $end =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]] on a new line?

Comment: (no, no on the test), it is `[[ $end =~ [[:digit:]]+ ]] || { printf "error: invalid integer.\n" >&2; exit 1; }` (that's a *compound-command* used as a shorthand 'if' that says either I'm a valid `int` OR throw the error and `exit` with error code of `1`) If you get stuck again, Edit your question and don't delete the current text, but ADD your new version of your script at the end and describe what problems you are having and everyone can help further.

Comment: The `>&2` just outputs the error on *stderr* instead of the normal *stdout*. You have three standard streams in bash (and most programming languages) `0 - stdin` for input, `1 - stdout` for normal output and `2 - stderr` for error output. The `>&2` is just short hand for redirecting *stdout* to *stderr* with `1>&2` (the `1` is implied and can be omitted)

Comment: You may also wonder why the `date` format of `'+%s.%N'`? It makes is super easy to use the nanosecond precision and also be able to get the original date/time back from the timestamp, e.g. enter `date -d "@1658008489.420120547"` on the command line to see the time from my first example above. (when using seconds since epoch for date input with the `-d` option, you precede the number of seconds with `'@'`)

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the amount of files you want to create: "
read $REPLY
for (( i=1; i<=$REPLY; i++ ))
do
         touch file$i-`date +%Y_%m_%d`.txt
done
```

`date +%Y_%m_%d` will help you to get the timestamp